# Serializing C# DateTime to JSON date with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, datetime, serialization

I have a C# model that, when serialized to JSON, should render the date property in JSON like: Date(123456790)

To achieve this I added the Attribute to the DateTime Property:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

However when the model is serialized, the resulting JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Member": {
        "FirstName": "firstname",
        "LastName": "lastname",
        "UserName": "username",
        "Password": "password",
        "FullName": "firstname lastname",
        "DateOfBirth": newDate(350546400000),
        "Gender": "male",
        "Email": "my@email.com"
    },
    "UserId": "b8a8fd7583b14d6a81bbaeb561aef765",
}
```

What I need it to look like is this:

```
{
    "Member": {
        "FirstName": "firstname",
        "LastName": "lastname",
        "UserName": "username",
        "Password": "password",
        "FullName": "firstname lastname",
        "DateOfBirth": "/Date(350546400000)/",
        "Gender": "male",
        "Email": "my@email.com"
    },
    "UserId": "b8a8fd7583b14d6a81bbaeb561aef765",
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm#DateTimeJsonConverters), the property to do this is DateFormatHandling, which should be MicrosoftDateFormat.

However I don't want to modify ALL conversions to this, just this model... so I attempted to create a custom serializer that would use that format:

```
public class CustomJavaScriptDateTimeConverter : JavaScriptDateTimeConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
        base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }
}
```

and updated the attribute to match:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomJavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

but although the custom serializer is hit, and the property is changed, the output is still the original "new Date(350546400000)" instead of what I want.

anybody know what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CustomConverter can be like this

```
public class CustomJavaScriptDateTimeConverter : JavaScriptDateTimeConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var js = new JsonSerializer() { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
        js.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: woohoo that was the one! thank you! may I ask how did you know this, is there a doc about how this works, I'd like to learn more, or was this just your expertise :) either way many thanks!